# NumberFormatter output is wrong on webserver, not on another one

Tags: php, nginx, unicode, utf-8, windows-1252

Context: we produce CSV and PDF files containing numbers formatted using French format (thousand separator is a no-break space).

When reading the CSV or PDF files, when downloaded from production server, we get a `?` character in place of the no-break space. When downloaded from our development server, we get proper files.

---

We have a small script which helped to provide a minimal reproduction.

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.date('YmdHis').'.txt"');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');

$fmt = new NumberFormatter('fr_FR', NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
$fmt->setAttribute(NumberFormatter::FRACTION_DIGITS, 2);

echo $fmt->format(12390);
```

That script works properly on a homestead virtual machine.

Hexadecimal content of the file which is downloaded is

```
31 32 c2 a0 33 39 30 2c 30 30
```

`c2 a0` being the [UTF-8 no-break space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space#Encodings)

When run on our production server, the exact same script outputs a file which contains the following hexadecimal content:

```
31 32 e2 80 af 33 39 30 2c 30 30
```

`e2 80 af` is what makes it different from the above. This seems to be the [narrow no-break space character from Unicode, encoded in UTF-8](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202f/index.htm)

What are we doing wrong?

- We have tried to compare PHP and Nginx configurations but they are very similar and could not find anything related to encoding.
- The mbstring extension is enabled on both sides.
- When we comment the header to force a download, the text is properly displayed by the browser on both servers (no `?`)

---

*Update*

For some reason, on a server, the `fr_FR` locale is using a regular non-breaking space. Whereas on the other server, the same code ends-up with a locale using a narrow non-breaking space.

Looks like there is poor support for the narrow non-breaking space in various tools.

Current workaround is to force the use of a regular non-breaking space and it ends-up working properly. This is by far not ideal.

If anyone has an explanation for why the same locale leads to different grouping symbol, I would be happy to read it and learn how to get a consistent setup between servers.

Comment: Where are you getting data from? Is it from database? Do both DBs have same scheme and all tables are set same?

Comment: See the script. Data is a hardcoded number formatted using NumberFormatter